# Understanding array of ArrayLists

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I'm creating an array of ArrayLists using the following code:

```
ArrayList<Integer>[] list = new ArrayList[n];
```

As it is said that array of generics is not allowed. How is that my code compiles?

Comment: My question is that even though people say that generic arrays are not allowed in java why is this code compiling for me: `ArrayList<Integer>[] list = new ArrayList[n];`

Comment: Because you aren't using full generics in that case; `new ArrayList[n]` is using the _raw type_ of `ArrayList`. The compiler should be emitting a warning saying that code is unsafe/unchecked. It's similar to casting a raw type to a generic type—it's allowed but isn't safe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are initializing an array not the ArrayList
Look at this:

```
ElementType [] name = new ElementType[size];
```

Here your element type is ArrayList

Look at this site:[Array of ArrayList](https://www.journaldev.com/744/java-array-of-arraylist-of-array)

Answer (score 0):

refer java documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/restrictions.html#createArrays). You cannot create arrays of parameterized types. if it were allowed you can then create generic lists which each element of a different type. That is just not allowed. The documentation explains this well